# Which is correct - "is started" or "has been started"

Tags: tenses

Please let me know which one is correct:

1. Some machine **is** started.
2. Some machine **has been** started.

#### Additional information:

I am reviewing message for software product. There when a user clicks "Start" button, an operation/entity starts.

Comment: ... or whether both are, or neither are.

Comment: They are both correct.

Comment: Your question title asks "what is the difference" but your actual question is "which one is correct?"  Which do you want?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

**some machine is started**

can mean a number of things:

Consider: some machines (e.g. so-called "simple machines", such as the lever) do not need to be started. More complex machines, like a table saw, must be started.  Given that context

**This machine is started**.

could mean "This is one of the machines that gets started or that one must start before using it."

It could also mean (although somewhat awkwardly): the machine is running.

**This machine is started at 7AM. We do not have a night-shift.**

That would mostly likely mean that the machine is turned on at 7AM.

To say

**The machine has been started**

could mean:

At some point in the past, someone turned this machine on. It may now be off or it may be on. But one thing is certain: it has been turned on at least once; it is not a machine that was never turned on.

or it could mean:

The machine is now running.  It was turned on, and it remains on.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to say the second one.

It can be argued that they both mean the same thing. "The machine is started" describes its current state as being *started*, implying that someone or something must have started it. "The machine has been started" directly confirms that its current state is the result of having been started.

However, as Tim mentioned, the first sounds quite awkward, as it's not common to use *started* as an adjective. That is why the second one is better.

It's possible that you derived "is started" from the contraction "The machine's started" which is more likely to be *The machine **has** started*. That may help to explain the uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question as it was kept on hold. Feel free to provide if you have any additional feedback.